# Cross Origin - Session Block

Tags: php, angularjs, session

I am working on AngularJS and PHP, I have an issue in setting session in cross origin. When I set a session in a page and retrieve it I get output, but I couldn't pass it to another page.

Comment: can you share more details on actual issue you are facing with example?

Comment: provide more details